# How to create a simple social sharing dropdown menu in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

How can I create a simple HTML/CSS social sharing menu similar to the one found at the bottom of each post on http://bitquill.com/ — (I know it's my site, but I didn't code the sharing menu. I'm using a Squarespace template and love their sharing menu and want to re-create it elsewhere.)

Comment: I don't even see what you are referring too.

Comment: Whoops, the link was pointing to the wrong place. Fixed now. My bad. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use an API from each site to get the buttons/badges. For example, you have to review the docs for the Facebook like button: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ and get the code that way.

To create the menu:

Make a share button using a `div`, then put another `div` after it, which is the menu. Style to your liking. Then, make the menu `display: none` - this will hide it. Use JS to bind the button's click event to a function that shows the menu:

**HTML**

```
<div class="share">Share</div>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Facebook</li>
        <li>Twitter</li>
        <li>Stack</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.className !== 'share')
        $('.menu').css('display', 'none');
    else 
        $('.menu').css('display', 'block');
});
```

---

So your entire HTML file should look like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .menu {
        display: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="share">Share</div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Twitter</li>
            <li>Stack</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- This is the jQuery -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('body').on('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target.className !== 'share')
            $('.menu').css('display', 'none');
        else 
            $('.menu').css('display', 'block');
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know, but I want to know how to build the dropdown menu in which you contain them all.

Comment: This is pretty much what I want, but for some reason the JS is not loading/working. I'm pretty new to JS, so any shot you could explain it to me like I'm a dummy?

Comment: I'm assuming you have jQuery: http://jquery.com/. That's what all the dollar signs refer to. If you don't, download it, and then reference it in your html using `<script src="path-to-jquery/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: I setup everything you said, but it's not working. I just have Share text that doesn't do anything when clicked. Maybe I setup jQuery wrong?

Comment: Perhaps. Do you mind posting just that script tag here? You also have to wrap the JS in a `$(document).ready(function () { ... });`

Comment: Ah, that's what I'm not doing I bet. How does that work? Right now, this is what I have (plus the bit of CSS in my stylesheet): http://d.pr/i/WjaA

Comment: You have to take the JS out of the script tag, and move it into another one. Also, remove the line `console.log(e)` since that's no use to you.

Comment: What's the JS versus the JQ? Sorry. Quite new to this, again. Any shot you can show me how the final code should look?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example. You set up a container div (which must have position:relative), and menu div (which has positioned:absolute). Use jQuery to hide the menu div when the page loads. When a user clicks on Share, the div will be displayed.

The API code that you get from Facebook will be placed in the div that has the Facebook placeholder text.

To see more about how the menu in your example was implemented, open the page using Chrome. Right click on "Share" and go to "Inspect Element."

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Initally hide social-menu div
        $("#social-menu").hide();

        //When social-button is pressed, show social-menu
        $("#social-button").click(function () {
            $("#social-menu").show();
        });
    });
```

```
<div id="social-button" >Share</div>          
    <div id="social-container" style="position:relative;">
    <div id="social-menu" style="position:absolute;top:0px;bottom:0px;z-index:10" >
        <div>Facbook</div>
        <div>Google +</div>
    </div>
</div>
```